# need maven plugin configuration for building aggregate source jar

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-dependency-plugin, maven-source-plugin

I've been fighting with this for a while and reading a lot of docs pages and other questions but still can't get it to work.

In my [ORMLite](http://ormlite.sourceforge.net/) project, I have a `ormlite-core` project which has core functionality and then a `-jdbc` and `-android` projects (with more planned).  Each of these sub-projects include the core functionality but add per-architecture implementations.  I want to release a single set of jars for both the `-jdbc` and `-android` versions -- i.e. I want to copy the `-core` javadocs and sources into the resulting jars.

For the javadocs, it was cake with the `includeDependencySources` config entry set to true.  However, I've been fighting for a while now on how to get the source jars released by the `-android` package to include the `-core` sources.  I've tried the `maven-dependency-plugin` to copy and unpack the dependency sources to `target/sources` but I see no easy way to get them to be included in the source jar -- with the appropriate paths.  I've gone over the `maven-source-plugin` and `maven-assembly-plugin` docs but I'm *still* in the dark.

If someone has figured out the magic maven fu to get this done, can they please share the appropriate working `pom.xml` examples?  Thanks much.

I've reviewed the following similar questions among others.  I've also looked at the [Sonatype Maven manual](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/public-book.html) and read a bunch web pages posing similar questions.

- [Delivering a single jar with a Maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873265/delivering-a-single-jar-with-a-maven-project)
- [Maven - 'all' or 'parent' project for aggregation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821077/maven-all-or-parent-project-for-aggregation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the best answer to this question at this time is "you can't get there from here".  This requires extensions to the `maven-source-plugin`.

I ended up determining that combining these sub-projects into the same jar was *not* a good idea and now I release 3 separate jars.

Answer (score 0):

While not an answer to the question, a possible reason why a parameter like `<includeDependencySources>` is not present for `maven source plugin` is because, while javadocs can be generated from a jar containing classes, the sources cannot be.  The plugin cannot assume that the sources of the dependencies are available to it since they do not get installed by default.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that javadocs gets generated from the _source_, not the class files.  If you do not have javadocs for a particular jar, you get class and method names but not even argument variable names and certainly none of the class or method documentation.

Comment: I certainly agree that it cannot amass a source jar from sources that it does not have access to but I think it should if it can.